# react.js and accessibility 508

Tags: reactjs, section508

I am new to React.JS. I built a web application using react.js. While running it, I took the source code of one of the displaying page and its html. Each element is identified by "data-reactid", understandably they follow dom structure. The question is when it comes to 508 accessibility compliance, how does the React.js support it?

For example a form element  uses "for" attribute pointing to the id of an  element to be 508 compliant. But react.js removes the "for" attribute.

Could somebody help me in forcing react.js to place "for" property? Or should I approach differently?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, use "htmlFor" instead of the "for". Thanks